# Linked list loop detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, floyd-cycle-finding

I read some interview question online about how would you find if there's a loop in a linked list, and solution ([Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare)) is to have two pointers, one is 2x faster than the other, and check if they meet again.

My question is: Why can't I just keep one pointer fixed, just move the other pointer forward by 1 step each time?

Comment: There's a somewhat faster modification of the algorithm, if anyone is curious: http://www.siafoo.net/algorithm/11

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Because the first (non-moving) pointer might not lie within the loop, so the pointers would never meet. (Remember that a loop may consist of only part of the list.)

Comment: That's clears it up. Thanks all, since I can only mark one correct answers I will mark the earliest one.

Answer (score 83):

Because maybe not the complete linkedList is within the loop.

For a linked list **lasso** detection algorithm, you need two pointers:

[image]

As long as the first pointer is where the cowboy is, no loop is detected. But if you move it stepwise forward, it will eventually enter the loop.

---

BTW, lasso is the terminus technicus from graph theory, cowboy isn't.

Answer (score 27):

Because the loop may not contain the element pointed to by the first pointer.

For example, if the first pointer points to element 1 and the linked list has a loop later on (1->2->3->4->2), your algorithm won't detect it.

Comment: just removed some minor typos so I can give you the 50+ in a week with good conscience (since you just missed being accepted by a couple of seconds).

Comment: @DaveBall Wow. Thanks. I'm glad you noticed. ;)